# UIWebView Text to Default Body style

Tags: ios, css, fonts, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that is being used to display a text only in html web page. It does have the following CSS

```
{ font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Arial', 'Serif' }
h1 { font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Bold'; font-size: 70px; text-transform: uppercase;}
img { width: 100%; height: auto;}
iframe { width: 100%x !important;}
.wp-smiley { width: auto !important;}
p, span { font-size: 70px; }
```

What can I do to either the css or the iOS application code so that it uses the default body style (e.g. `Font: Text Styles - Body`).

Thanks

Comment: Do you want same font for the whole body of the html?

Comment: No, I'd like to use the iOS default fonts for 'body,' 'headline,' and 'subhead.' So i'm willing to remove the css (or modify) if there is a way to display the fonts with those default styles. Meaning i don't specify font names, sizes, etc.

If that's not possible, then i'm willing to hard code it to the default ios7 sizes, fonts. I don't know what the sizes are in px.

Answer (score 0):

To have the same font for all the elements of the html, you need to style the `body tag` like below

```
body{ font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Arial', 'Serif' }
```